# Weird Speed Issue

Tags: networking, router, speed

My internet speed should be 1 MB but the actual speed I'm downloading with now is 256 KB. I called my ISP and they said that the speed has been reduced to 256 KB because I'm downloading lots of things ('bad usage').

Now, the problem is in the router page written that the data rate still 1175 (1MB).

I need to know if they just changed something in the setting of my router which caused that reduction of my speed, and can I turn my speed back by doing anything or what?

Screenshot from my router:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ISP didn't do this in your router. The ISP is throttling you bandwidth in the ISP's network.

Your terms of service with the ISP probably have a limitation on the amount of data you are allowed to use per month. If you exceed this limit, the ISP will throttle your bandwidth until the next billing period.

You need to discuss this with your ISP. You may be able to upgrade to a tier allowing more data per month, but that is up to your ISP and what service offerings it provides.

Comment: Sure. We just can't do these types of questions on Network Engineering because the questions and answers are archived forever, and the site is reserved for network professionals asking and answering questions about professional networks. Before the site was created, such questions were lost in the noise of all the other types of questions Super User.

Comment: I understand the rules now, sorry this was my first time to use sites like this :).